# Grails params from GSP to controller are null

Tags: javascript, grails

I have this button:

```
<button id = "select"
            onclick = "<g:remoteFunction controller='customer' action='selectBatch'/>"
            params: '\'batchID=\' + selectedBatchID'>Select</button>
```

which does call this method in my controller:

```
def selectBatch = {
    println "Batch Selected: " + params.batchID
}
```

but with this output:

```
Batch Selected: null
```

Here is the related javascript that generates and prepares the variable to be passed in the params:

```
var table = document.getElementById('batchTble'),
rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
var selectedBatchID;

for (var i=0,len=rows.length; i<len; i++){
rows[i].onclick = function(){
    console.log(this.cells[0].innerHTML);
    selectedBatchID = parseInt(this.cells[0].innerHTML);
    console.log(selectedBatchID)
    /* if you know it's going to be numeric:
    console.log(parseInt(this.innerHTML),10);
    */
}
```

I did confirm that the javascript variable "selectedBatchID" does print to the console so it does indeed hold a value. But the value never makes it into the params that the controller gets for some reason. Here is what the Chrome debug console give me at the same time as the controller complains about null:

```
17 VM3216:53
POST http://ec2-54-209-146-139.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/FatcaOne_0/customer/selectBatch 404 (Not Found) jquery.tools.min.js:38
send jquery.tools.min.js:38
onclick
```

You can see that the value '17' printed in the Chrome debug console but never makes it into the controller as params.batchID. Why my param is null and I get the 404 not found is what I do not understand? Any help appreciated. I'd be happy to provide more details on request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onclick` looks incorrect. Refer [docs](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Tags/remoteFunction.html) for details. Based on that it should be something like:

```
<button id = "select"
        onclick = "${remoteFunction(controller: 'customer', 
                                    action: 'selectBatch',
                                    params: '\'batchID=\' + selectedBatchID')}">
Select
</button>
```

I suppose you have mixed the taglib and method call syntax as shown in the question (usage of key-value for params versus attributes for action and controller). Moreover, `params` is not part of `remoteFunction` altogether in the question.

Comment: Thanks again to you sir. It solved the param being null issue but I still get the 404 not found in the Chrome debug console. Any idea on that?

Comment: I do not see where it listens to the callback once the ajax call is complete. I suggest to go through the doc linked in the answer again.

Comment: Thank you I will read the docs again just to get a better understanding as you suggested. I have only been using Grails for a month but full time at that. I have made rapid progress but still LOTS to learn. Its a beautiful framework. Regards.